# How to add a <T> type argument to a function called from an MVC3 Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've written a function to output an enum as RadioButtons in a group (based on code answers found on here...blatantly stolen!)

However, the function takes a type argument  - and I can't work out how to call it from the View?

I've tried the two snippets below...the first works correctly, but doesn't output anything, and I can't work out how to get the second to take  ?

```
@{
    Html.RadioButtonForEnum<RuleType>("Rule");   
}

@Html.RadioButtonForEnum<RuleType></RuleType> <--this gets autocompleted for me!
```

I've a feeling this is going to be simple...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make your code block explicit. Try:

```
@(Html.RadioButtonFor<RuleType>("Rule"))
```